# Lie group Definition ambiguity

Tags: group-theory

i'm taking a qft theory class, and we are doing a little bit of group theory, today the professor introduced us to Lie groups, but his definition is a little be weird he said that lie groups are groups whose elements  are function of n parameters.
This kinda confuses me and i can not see how this definition is equivalent to the one where a Lie Group is defined as smooth manifold with some other proprieties like the operation of the group be differentiable.
Anyone can help me to clarify and get how these two definitions are equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: What is qft theory?

Comment: Yeah, that definition makes no sense. I'm guessing the Lie Groups you are going to see in physics are mostly matrix groups, which are (isomorphic to) some set of linear functions in n variables.

Comment: It’s the barest of a heuristic, far from a definition.

Comment: It is not a definition to me.

Comment: Extremely heuristic, as others have mentioned. The part about ‘elements are functions of $n$ parameters’ is trying to describe that the underlying smooth manifold is $n$-dimensional (when you write things out in a local chart you’ll need $n$ component functions). Looks like they’re just trying to avoid the word ‘manifold’ and all the preliminaries that come with explaining its definition.

Comment: It is as good a definition as any other in physics (which means: not good at all for math).

Comment: Most of the group i ll use in quantum field theory are matrix, still i didn't get why he introduced it like a "proper" definition, i studied a little bit more in these hours and i get his point but that was no near to a formal math def, thanks to everyone  p.s as you pointed out i think he was trying to say that he s assuming to use a local coordinate chart, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a definition. At best it's a heuristic description of a [local Lie group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+Lie+group), meaning what the multiplication on a Lie group looks like in a sufficiently small neighborhood of the origin (although even then it's missing the condition that the multiplication should be smooth), where we can work in local coordinates.

For some purposes in physics this is enough since the local behavior of multiplication in a neighborhood of the origin is enough to recover the [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra), and for some purposes you only need to work with the Lie algebra. It even seems to be common among physicists to ignore the distinction between Lie groups and Lie algebras - if you care about this sort of thing you are likely more of a mathematician than a physicist! But this is not remotely a clear enough description of what a global Lie group is.

Anyway, don't ask physicists to teach you rigorous Lie theory, that's what mathematicians are for.

Comment: ok thank you, so it's not a proper definition that's what i thought too, the only thing to make my head around was to make some sort of heuristic reasoning and like you said, use that definition when you have already introduced a linear representation and you re workin localy, thank you very much for the clarification